# If a flight was postponed, does the passenger have to pay to extend the ticket?

Tags: air-travel, aircraft, cancellations

My friend's flight was postponed to a yet unknown date due to a fault in the plane. He has a round trip, he has 2 stops before he reaches his destination. He was planning on staying there for 3 weeks.

However, his ticket back here is still 3 weeks from the original date. Does he have the right to extend his ticket date for free? Or does he have to pay to extend his departure date to come back?

**For example**, he was supposed to depart on 31 July but, it got postponed to 3 August, and he was supposed to come back 3 weeks after his departure. So does he have the right to return on 25/8 with no extra charges, or does he have to pay to postpone his ticket, which was originally 21 August?

Comment: You may want to give some geographical context to the question. The answer may change from place to place and if this subject is not regulated it may even depend on the airline company "kindness level".

Comment: @nsn His postponed flight was to London, so I'm guessing British Airlines

Comment: In general it would be unusual for a BA flight to require 2 stops before reaching London.

Comment: @phoog no, he's going to the US, to do that he must go to London, from London he goes to Florida, from Florida to his destination.

Comment: In that case then yes it is likely that the airline is British Airways.

Comment: I'd find it very unusual if BA would postpone a flight for 3 days. Not unless there's a new ash cloud crisis or something

Comment: @Berwyn there's a fault in the plane, so yeah...

Comment: And so far it's been 2 days

Comment: What airport is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering the airline in question is British Airways, you should be able to change any other flights if they are in the same booking.

> If you are booked to travel on a flight that is cancelled, you can
>   either:
>
> Rebook onto another British Airways flight at a later date at no extra
>   charge and subject to availability OR
>
> Cancel your booking and claim a refund to the original form of payment
>
> If your booking also includes any other BA flights that are not
>   cancelled you will be able to change these flights at the same time.

Source : http://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/help-in-disruption/rebooking-options

The question remains if you get the same class while rescheduling because if you don't then you will have to pay DOF (Difference of Fare) charges.

This is an airline specific question, such conditions are subject to airline policy and they are the best place to contact for information. If your flight wasn't BA then this won't be applicable.

Comment: It turns out his flight was Middle East Airlines (I'm horrible at this stuff... Don't think of me as stupid), and I cannot seem to find their rules. Can you link me?

Comment: They are liable to compensation, it's mentioned on their website but details aren't given. It's best if you call them https://www.mea.com.lb/english/Support/Call-Center

Answer (score -2):

This entirely depends on the fare rules.  If a flight is delayed due to a preventable condition (such as a mechanical fault in your case), then the airline should compensate you for the delay and book you on the next available flight for free.

How they compensate, and to what level - this depends on the airline, and sometimes on the itinerary; and sometimes even on which class of travel you are flying.

In addition to the compensation, airlines offer to ignore or reduce fees for rebooking, or any penalties for cancellation of the ticket if there is a preventable delay.

The airline's liability is to take you to your destination; that's all. In other words, the liability is limited to each leg of the flight - there are normally two legs to a round trip flight (the departure leg, and the return leg).

In simple terms - what this means is that your delay when arriving at your destination, does not entitle to you any compensations on the return flight; in other words - if your inbound flight was delayed *and you took the flight*, it does not entitle you to any compensation or reduction in fees when scheduling the return leg of the flight.

Comment: What are the downvotes for? Can anyone help explain?

Comment: @GayotFow I didn't downvote it, but I didn't really understand what it was trying to say. The question is "Does he have the right to extend his ticket date for free?" and the answer is mainly about compensation. I don't see what preventable or non-preventable delays have got to do with anything either.

Comment: @Berwyn tar, understood